# Move certain lines to the preceding line

Tags: bash, formatting

I have a list that looks like this:

```
sharename:shareX
comment:commentX
sharename:shareY
comment:commentY
sharename:shareZ
comment:commentZ
```

and so on...

And this is how I would like the list to look like:

```
shareX;commentX
shareY;commentY
shareZ;commentZ
```

How can I accomplish that in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one liner:

```
odd=0; for i in `cat list | cut -d":" -f2`; do if [ $odd -eq 0 ]; then echo -ne $i; odd=1; else echo $i; odd=0; fi; done
```

formatted:

```
odd=0; 
for i in `cat list | cut -d":" -f2`; 
do 
    if [ $odd -eq 0 ]; 
    then 
        echo -ne $i";"; 
        odd=1; 
    else 
        echo $i; 
        odd=0; 
    fi; 
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to change IFS too, because some comments had space and comma in them.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash:

```
IFS=':'
while read a b; read c d; do   # read 2 lines
  echo -e "$b:$d"
done < "$infile"
```

Answer (score 0):

untested, the sed part may be wrong

```
paste -d ';' - - < filename | sed -r 's/(^|;)[^:]:/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '$!N;s/[^:]*:\([^\n]*\)\n[^:]*:/\1;/' file
shareX;commentX
shareY;commentY
shareZ;commentZ
```